# Почему не работает регулярное выражение в Java?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть строка:

```
String str = "Первая строка! Вторая строка?\nТретья строка! Четвертая строка.";
```

Вопрос, почему вот это:

```
for(String s : string.trim().split("[!?.]"))
        System.out.println(s);
```

не убирает лишний пробел перед словом `(с помощью метода trim)`?

Вывод на консоль (печатаются пробелы перед началом строк):

```
Первая строка
 Вторая строка
 Третья строка
 Четвертая строка
```

Если только использовать здесь - `System.out.println(s.trim())`

И второй вопрос:

Не могу понять, как в `split()` задать регулярное выражение, чтобы ещё игнорировался символ `\n` в совокупности с регулярным выражением `split("[!?.]")`?

Пробовал `split("[!?.]^[\n]")` - не получается.

Comment: потому что вы вызываете сначала трим, а потом сплит. таким образом, трим рассматривает строку целиком и образает первый и последний пробелы, а после того, как вы вызываете сплит ваши свежесозданные строки никакой трим уже не обрабатывает.

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать тогда так 'string.split("[!?.]").trim()' ?

Comment: а потому что в этом случае вы вызываете трим у того, что возвращает сплит, а сплит возвращает массив, в то время как трим - это метод стринга. вызывайте его в цикле у переменной s (можете прямо в System.out.println)

Comment: Хорошо, понятно. А вторая часть вопроса. Есть предложение с запятой "Слово раз, два". Как разбить это предложение на слова, чтобы в String не вносился знак запятой?
str.split(" ") разделяет слово с запятой.

Comment: легко split(" |, ")

Comment: Вот это для моего случая - split("\p{P}?[ \t\n\r]+"). Только не могу понять, что это означает. По отдельности регулярные выражения понятны, но в совокупности...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разберём выражение `split("\\p{P}?[ \t\n\r]+")` по буквам:

- `\\p{P}` - любой знак пунктуации. Второй слэш для экранирования
- `?` - 0 или 1 символ
- квадратные скобки - символьный класс. Означает любое из перечисленных значений.
- `\t\n\r` - соответственно пробел, символ табуляции и символы перевода строки: " ", "\t", "\n", "\r".
- `+` - один и более символов

Соберём всё вместе:

Необязательный знак пунктуации, после которого следует 1 или более пробелов, символов табуляции или символов перевода строки.

Текст разделяется по такому условию.

Если выполнить этот код, то получим:

```
[Первая, строка, Вторая, строка, Третья, строка, Четвертая, строка.]
```

Не совсем то, что хочется. Заменим вопросительный знак на плюсик.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream("Первая строка! Вторая строка?\nТретья строка! Четвертая строка.".split("\\p{P}+[ \t\n\r]+")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Результат:

```
[Первая строка, Вторая строка, Третья строка, Четвертая строка.]
```

То, что требовалось.

Comment: Всегда задавался вопросом, что означает + - один или более символов? В совокупности с [символьным классом]? Означает, что либо один из символов, заключенных в [квадратный скобки] либо любая комбинация из этих символов (все символы, либо два, либо три и т.д.)?

Comment: Любая комбинация из этих символов, в количестве 1 или более. В этих примерах везде будет true:

"a12".matches("[abc]+12")
"ca12".matches("[abc]+12")
"abca12".matches("[abc]+12")
"aaa12".matches("[abc]+12")